# Regarding validity of the EMC/EMI & safety test reports containing withdrawn IEC Standards for CE & UKCA declaration

Tags: emc, testing, ce

I do have a question regarding the validity of the EMI/EMC & Safety test reports of the products which do have the withdrawn IEC standards.

Like for an Example: If we do have tested the products according to IEC 61326-1:2012 standard. For declaration of CE we have to use the EN 61326-1:2013 (Latest generation at the moment) standard as a harmonized standard which is identical to the 2012 standard from IEC . The current gen of IEC standard is IEC 61326-1:2020. But the declaration is according to EN standard of 2013 edition.

Then the previous test reports would be valid or there is any need for retesting of the products?

Also please provide link to check the validity of the EN standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as the EU EMC Directive is concerned, the only thing that applies is the version of the standard currently listed as harmonised. You can find a list of harmonised standards here:
[Directive 2014/30/EU on electromagnetic compatibility - Summary list as pdf document](https://ec.europa.eu/docsroom/documents/45365/attachments/1/translations/en/renditions/native)

It still says EN 61326-1:2013, so that is the one which applies. That is, at least in EU + countries applying the EU directives. It might not be the case world-wide.

When doing EMC testing, you should check with the test house if tests are compatible between the 2013 and 2020 versions. If not, they might be able to add some test to ensure this and then you'll get that stated in the report. Or maybe it is an option do the test against 2020, but claim compliance against the older version. You'll need someone with in-depth knowledge of the particular standard to tell - check with the test house.

Also note that in case of the CE mark, you often have the option to demonstrate compliance without 3rd party testing. So in case changes are minor and not affecting your product, while you've tested against the old version and made no product changes, you should be able to guarantee compliance without further testing.

Otherwise, if you release a product claiming EN 61326-1:2013 compliance and at a later point the newer version of the standard becomes the active one, you would indeed have to do the tests again. Or in case the technical differences are minor, perhaps some complementary test. And in some cases, changes don't affect the testing at all.

However, products already put on the market will not be affected in case they change the standard - only products put on the market from the point when the change is made. When this happens there's usually a transition period. Also, in case of EU directives, they tend to do a major revision every 10 years or so, and update the list of standards at that point.

My general advise when dealing with all the constant standard and directive changes is to make the best effort you can. If you've done EMC testing for one version and that one becomes inactive, you are still in a much better place than if you haven't done any testing at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot Lundin for the info.